# How to display the existing (but hidden) WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, .net-5

I am creating a WinForm application (**.Net-5, .Net Core**). The instance of my WinForm could be minimized/Hidden. Whenever I start my application, I need to check if there is an existing instance of the application already running. If there is already an existing instance then, I need to display its WinForm instead of creating new one.

In the code below, I am always checking if there is an existing process. **If yes, how can I display open its Form/GUI?**

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var runningProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
       
        if (runningProcess.Length>1) // Already running processes
        {
            //Get our previous instance
            Process myProcess = runningProcess[0];

            //How to SHOW the already exisitng (but minimized) instance of the Form?
            //--?
            //--?

        }
        else
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MyGUI());
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user9938 : The useful part from the link is to use the code `SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);`. I tried to use it but it does not bring the hidden window of my previous instance to front. So, not working for me :(

Comment: See the `RestoreWindow()` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71589883/7444103) + `BringWindowToTop()`

Comment: Back in the Win32 time frame, I worked on a multi app suite. We wanted only one instance of any app running and we wanted some other interapp communication. We used the COM running object table to manage all this. At startup, we'd check if there was another instance of the app running, if so, we'd tell it how we were called. That instance would pop to the front and respond to the startup info. If no other instance was running, we'd register the current instance. We'd unregister when we closed. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835617/understanding-the-running-object-table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697058/single-instance-windows-forms-application-and-how-to-get-reference-on-it/699701#699701

Comment: .NET 5 is no longer supported. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

.NET 5 is no longer supported. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core) for more information. You may consider moving your project to .NET 6.

The following shows a way to ensure only a single instance of one's Windows Forms App is running. If it's minimized or hidden it'll be shown. The code has been tested with a new `Windows Forms App` project (.NET 6) on Windows 10.

In the code below, when the form is hidden, `p.MainWindowHandle` is IntPtr.Zero. Therefore, it's necessary to find the window handle another way. I've used [FindWindowA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) which uses the window title to find the desired window as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847481/showwindowasync-dont-show-hidden-window-sw-show). `Form1` is the default form that exists when one creates a new Windows Forms project - the form's window text "Form1" should be changed to your desired window title.

**Program.cs**:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestAllowSingleInstance
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern IntPtr FindWindowA(string? lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

            //sets window's show state - doesn't wait for operation to complete
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName(curProcess.ProcessName))
                {
                    if (p.Id != curProcess.Id && p.MainModule?.FileName == curProcess.MainModule?.FileName)
                    {
                        //set as foreground (ie: show on top of other windows)
                        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);

                        if (IsIconic(p.MainWindowHandle))
                        {
                            //minimized
                            ShowWindowAsync(p.MainWindowHandle, 9); //SW_RESTORE = 9
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            IntPtr hwnd = p.MainWindowHandle;

                            //when the window is hidden, the MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero
                            if (p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                            {
                                //window is hidden, find it by the title

                                //"Form1" is the title that is displayed on the Window
                                hwnd = FindWindowA(null, "Form1");
                            }

                            ShowWindowAsync(hwnd, 1); //SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1; SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
                        }

                        //set focus
                        SetFocus(p.MainWindowHandle);

                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [How to force C# .net app to run only one instance in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184084/how-to-force-c-sharp-net-app-to-run-only-one-instance-in-windows)
- [ShowWindowAsync() don't show hidden window (SW_SHOW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847481/showwindowasync-dont-show-hidden-window-sw-show)
- [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Process.GetCurrentProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Process.GetProcessByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.8)
- [FindWindowA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa)
- [IsIconic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic)
- [SetFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus)
- [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow)
- [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow)
- [ShowWindowAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindowasync)